Using the @override method in my package? Issues and workarounds?
In python, I am developing a package which has the following two classes:
I have a parent class:
class Parent:
    def my_method(self):
        return 1

and I have a child class that overrides this method of the parent class:
from typing import override
class Child(Parent):
    @override
    def my_method(self):
        return 2

I am using the @override decorator when overriding the method. But the overriding decorator is available in the typing module only in python 3.12 and above. Therefore my package will require a really latest version of python and users will face an extra install step.
How do I work around this so that my package can be downloaded with earlier releases of python as well?

You can import override from typing_extensions instead.
